# Why i get error when use Bot.Me.FirstName in c# TelegramBotSharp?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I'm new in Telegram bot and write this simple code:

```
Bot = new TelegramBot("305316106:AAGnCZeZtoc3FtzuyGbmB2B0yJ2dtZxua0M");
Console.WriteLine("Hi , My name is :{0} , ANd My ID is :{1}",Bot.Me.FirstName);
Console.ReadKey();
```

but when I run that code I get this error

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list.

What's happening? How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: because writeline waits second value from you, ID parameter value

Comment: You forgot the argument for `{1}`... you only provided `Bot.Me.FirstName` to `Console.WriteLine()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` is expecting a second argument (The format you are providing has two placeholders):

```
Console.WriteLine("Hi , My name is :{0} , ANd My ID is :{1}", Bot.Me.FirstName, Bot.Me.Id);
```